# Can SharePoint 2013/Online act as authentication provider for a SaaS

Tags: authentication, claim-provider, oauth

I have found lots of documentation about how to login to SharePoint using Google, Facebook, Microsoft Account, etc. But can you make it the other way around?

Can SharePoint act as an authentication provider for Third party apps and services? I'm looking into offering a seamless experience for users of Our customers' SharePoint intranets to be automatically logged into our Java web Application (SaaS).

Obviously we would need to extend our saas to support this, but can we use SharePoint's New OAuth support in any way, or STS as claims provider? Let us say that we have multiple customers that run SharePoint online.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a lot of time searching the same answer than you. At this point, I couldn't find an answer yet but I will tell you my idea.

I don't know how to use sharepoint as an identity provider, but you can use ADFS v2 to act as well. ADFS will be your STS. First you need to configure Sharepoint and ADFS together (I found [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx) for Sharepoint 2010)  Obviously, as you said, also you would need to extend your SaaS to support ADFS.

Using ADFS, you will have multiple applications all trusting in a single authentication source, thus providing a SSO experience for your users.

Comment: I haven't found any solution to this either, so I assume that it is not supported.

Comment: To provide single sign-on capabilities to our Java based SaaS, I think our strongest bet is to build support for Azure authentication. Azure authentication is used by SharePoint Online. To support SSO for customers hosting their own SharePoint, I Guess ADFS is the only alternative

Comment: Just to add additional info, I followed this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235(v=office.15).aspx) to configure ADFS and all worked fine